# Unintended change in AdWords Flash to HTML5 conversion

Tags: editing

my company wants to run some advertisements on Google AdWords. We made some animated Flash ads, however AdWords automatically converts the ads from Flash to HTML5 with some unintended changes. See below the difference between the two. It seems that when moving an image it's a lower quality than when it's finished moving.

Flash:

[image: flash]

HTML5: (pay attention to when the images stop moving)

[image: html5]

Anyone have an idea how to prevent that from happening? Made the individual vector images in Illustrator and imported them in Flash to make the animation. Only used a simple motion tween to move the image inside the screen.

Comment: I'm not sure that this qualifies as Video Production.  They may be animated ads, but it really doesn't seem like it is video.  I'll hold off on closing until the community has a chance to voice if they think it is video or not though.

Comment: I have created a [question on Meta](http://meta.video.stackexchange.com/questions/391/are-questions-about-flash-animations-ads-on-topic/) to discuss if this kind of question is on topic.

Comment: Asked it here since I was working with a timeline similar to other video software. The Anti Aliasing mentioned by FartSparkle is definitely something I'l take a look at.

Comment: yeah, it's really borderline territory.  I know Flash, but have always characterized it as a more programmatic scripting and animation package.  It's a very odd product in terms of where it fits between animation and game/software development.  It's roots are very much in simplifying the use of animation in programs, but it made major efforts to expand in to doing animations and video playback since they did such a good job with the vector animation parts.  So far nobody has spoken up either way though, so I'll leave it unless some kind of consensus emerges.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to export as HTML5 from Flash directly instead of relying on Googles conversion.
This has to do with how the Google conversion is animating this. It's probably based on an HTML5 canvas which can have Anti Aliasing disabled in certain events to improve performance.
Google maybe also enforce this to have a pleasant web performance for users. Flash has generally very poor performance because of things like that.

You might want to ask this on Stackoverflow instead, this is more a web programming question.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't choose whether or not you want an HTML5 version. The only option is to enable mobile ads (which is required if you want ads to show on tablets for example). And at that moment they automatically use the HTML5 version. Thanks for the insight though!

Comment: In the newer version of Flash (I believe CS5.5+) you can choose to export to HTML5 instead of an .swf

Comment: Yes, but AdWords themselves do not accept HTML5 ads, only .swf files. They convert it to HTML5 for you. Doubleclick Rich Media ads are supposed to support HTML5 ads though.

Comment: Ah I see. Well, like I said, you should ask this question on http://stackoverflow.com/. You will get more and better answers there.